# Printing current year in polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm kinda new to polymer but I was wondering if there is a way to print the current year and put that in my footer that way I can always have a up to date copyright notice.

I've tried Javascript but it just doesn't work, any help would be amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a Polymer element](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements) that [contains a property](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/properties) initialized to the current year (determined from [`Date#getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)):

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  class XCopyright extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-copyright'; }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        year: {
          type: String,
          value: () => new Date().getFullYear()
        }
      };
    }
  }
  customElements.define(XCopyright.is, XCopyright);
});
```

```css
main {
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.1.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <main></main>
  <footer>
    <x-copyright></x-copyright>
  </footer>

  <dom-module id="x-copyright">
    <template>
      <span>&copy; {{year}}</span>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qPJxLj)